# Sync/Transfer DB from Localhost to Remote too slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, synchronization

I have a large chunk of database available at about 100 GB. The records would be synced with the remote database. Each record must be checked with db online and if not available then to be update/inserted to db. I have tried some methods to increase the speed but it is transferring at too slow a speed. The methods I tried are:

1. Simple script to match the record and uploading the database to which the speed is very very slow.
2. Generated MySQL dump then compressed it and transferred to online, then online check and update them. The dump was too big to transfer (it was taking a long time to transfer).

Kindly suggest other methods to transfer the DB.

Answer (score 0):

try mysqldumper :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqldumper/files/

it can take mysql dump and restore, its awesome its speed is good.